# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MatchList')

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I have this:

```
let list = GetList(JSON.stringify(data),"");
console.log( list.SearchResult.MatchList);
```

and I have this issue:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MatchList')`

I added console logo to list `console.log(list);`

I get this :

```
{
  SearchResult: { MatchList: [ [Object] ], numOfMatches: 1, totalMatches: 1 }
}
```

this is in console, why I can't get `MatchList`

console

```
let list = GetList(JSON.stringify(data),"");
console.log( list );
```

I get

```
{
  SearchResult: { MatchList: [ [Object] ], numOfMatches: 1, totalMatches: 1 }
}
```

getlist function:

```
  exports.GetList = async (req, res) => {   
   
    const data = await petition({
      url: URLGateway,
      method: 'POST',
      body: req,
    });

    return data; 
  };
```

get petition function:

```
 const petition = async ({url, method, contentype, body}) => { 

    const URL =  process.env.URL + url;
    const USER = process.env.USER;
    const PASS = process.env.PASSWORD;

    try
    {            
        const options = {
            method: method,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            digestAuth: `${USER}:${PASS}`,
            contentType: contentype,
            data: body,
        };
        
        const responseHandler = (err, data, res) => { 
            if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", err);
            }
        }

        const { data } = await httpClient.request(URL, options, responseHandler); 
        const result =  JSON.parse( data.toString('utf8') );
        
        return {
            res: result,
        }; 

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        console.log("Exception: ", Exception);
    } 
  }

  module.exports = petition;
```

the function Getlist call function petition, This function allows me to obtain the data that is in the endpoint ( url )

Comment: Can you show us the console.log(list) that works in the actual code?

Comment: ok, just checking because it might have been a promise or something and when it worked was because you put await in front...
I do not see any problem in there. if you log list and on the line right after you log list.SearchResult, you see the list but get the error, right? Could we see GetList maybe??

Comment: I added both functions that i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I was thinking... `console.log(list)` is not giving you that return, it certainly gives you `Promise` something. `GetList` returns a promise (because of the `async` keyword) and a promise does not have `SearchResult`. You need to await first.

```
// Either await the before storing into list:
let list = await GetList(JSON.stringify(data),"");
console.log( list.SearchResult.MatchList);
// Or await before using the value
console.log((await list).SearchResult.MatchList);
```

Comment: I added  ```let list  = await GetList(JSON.stringify(data),"");
let array = list .SearchResult.MatchList;``` but I get issue again ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MatchList')

```

Comment: Then there's something else... Could you log list before assigning the array?

Comment: I fixed it by deleting ```JSON.parse``` of  ```const result =  JSON.parse( data.toString('utf8') );``` of function petition... thanks bro!